# Control speed of TextToSpeech (TTS)

Tags: android

Is there any way I can have greater control over "how" the TTS is saying instead of "what" it is saying?

- pitch
- speed of pronunciation
- male/female
- any other options?

[The API comes up short](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just came across this and surprised nobody had answered.

Try using setPitch or setSpeechRate.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setPitch(float)

Comment: @MarkLapasa I tried setting setPitch as well as setSpeechRate, but the voice is either not clear or not audible.. I thought that there was some problem with my phone.. so tried installing Google Translate App.. and it worked really well. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can you please help?

Answer (score 8):

With TTS u can use these methods to control speak

- addSpeech(String text, String filename)
  //This method adds a mapping between a string of text and a sound file.
- getLanguage()
  ////This method returns a Localeinstance describing the language.
- isSpeaking()//This method checks whether the TextToSpeech engine is busy speaking.
- setPitch(float pitch)//This method sets the speech pitch for the TextToSpeech engine.
- setSpeechRate(float speechRate)//This method sets the speech rate.
- shutdown()//This method releases the resources used by the TextToSpeech
- stop()//This method stop the speak.